# Error: No such file or directory while archiving iOS and WatchOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, archive, watchos-2

i have a problem which puzzles me a few days now and i cannot find a solution.
What i want to do is **archiving** an iOS app including a watchOS app in Xcode.

The normal debug build (of both iOS App and WatchOS App) works fine on real devices and simulators (note: CocoaPods included). But when i try to archive the project the following error occurs:

> error:
>   /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/BuildProductsPath/Release-watchos/AppNameWatch.app:
>   No such file or directory

I tried to clean up everything, delete the DerivedData folder, restart Xcode, delete the App from the devices, restart the Mac... but nothing solves the problem. I also tried to archive without CocoaPods integration (I removed CocoaPods from my Project completely). I also played around with the target build phases (removing the embedded watch content).

Maybe somebody has an idea...

Thanks

Steffen

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: I am having the same issue.. Anyone solved this?

Comment: Any solution? What a crazy issue...

Comment: 7 years later, still happening

Answer (score 10):

I managed to solve this error, marked as `PBCXCp Error`, by correcting my **Target Dependencies** from **Project->Build Phases**. Here is how the **Target Dependencies** should look:

**iOS app target**

[image]

**Watch app target**

[image]

**Watch extension target**

[image]

I've accidentally added my iOS app as a target dependency to my watch extension target and that generated the error.

Hope it helps, cheers.